# Error to execute the game Battlefield 4 in Windows 10 (0xc000007b)

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, runtime-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2PJf.png)

It already made a long time that I'm having this issue, I've already tried to download and install the VCC++ all programs and tutorials in the internet, I've tried to re-install the game too, it didn't work. But I can't solve this, I don't know more what I have to do, the EA support is ridiculous, they help me nothing.

Message error:

```
BFLauncher_x86.exe - Application Error
The application can't be initialized correctly (0xc000007b). Click Ok to close the application.
```

I'm trying to open the game Battlefield 4, Battlefield 1 and have others that I can't open as well.
Don't you know what is this?

I've already tried to download and install the VCC++ all programs and tutorials in the internet, I've tried to re-install the game.